# Python: Check if a value is in each list in a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a question regarding if a quick way exist to check if each value in a list is in each sublist of a list of lists.

```
word = ['Elevator','Cats Allowed','Hardwood Floors',...] # length could be 100. No duplicate exists in this list.
features =[['Hardwood Floors','Doorman',...],['Pre-War', 'Dogs Allowed', 'Cats Allowed',...],[...]] # a list of lists;length could be ~150,000
```

What I know is I can do double loop iterate over word and features. Just wondering if there is a quicker way? because I found double loop is very slow in my case.

What I expect is something like:

```
for each_word in word:
    each_word in features?
```

I wish for every iteration over word, it returns a vector of boolean for each_word (namely, if each_word is in every sublist of features, it returns a vector of all true [true,true,....,true];if each_word is not in any sublist, it returns vector of all False; Otherwise if returns a mixed vector of True or False.

Thank you

Comment: If you want to make this quicker, use `sets` instead of `lists`.

Comment: Are you interested in exactly which sublists the word is in, or are you content to know whether the word is any or all of them?

Comment: A [mcve] would be nice, with matching and non-matching values, else it's too broad as iafisher noted in his question. for example your list of words is a,b,c ... when your other list contains real words. So please provide a small list of words, and small list of list of other words, and the expected result, possibly obtained with the inefficient code you seem able to write.

Comment: @iafisher, i am just interested in whether a single word is in each sublist of that list of lists. for each word, the boolean vector is important to me.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre. I just edited a little bit hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if all of the words are in any of the lists:

```
 set(words).issubset(set([item for sublist in features for item in sublist]))
```

Edit: Ok, if you want to know if each word is in the list, I would do:

```
s = set([item for sublist in features for item in sublist]
[word in s for word in words]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sets will definitely speed up your code as Roelant suggested, and you can make it nice and concise with list comprehensions:

```
features_set = list(map(set, features))
for word in words:
    vector = [(word in subset) for subset in features_set]
    # do something with the vector
```